# Python: Join/merge two panda dataframe with pivot function using False/True

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, pivot

I have two dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2,3],'param1': ['foo','bar','fu'],'param2': ['fo', 'ba','bar']})

   id param1 param2
0   1    foo     fo
1   2    bar     ba
2   3     fu    bar

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 1,1,2,2,3],'item': ['X','Y','Z','X','Z','Y'],})

   id item
0   1    X
1   1    Y
2   1    Z
3   2    X
4   2    Z
5   3    Y
```

I like to join/merge the two frames with the key `id`. However I want the frame to be expanded so each unique item becomes its own column, and each row is filled with 0 or 1. I guess its a kind of maping with a pivot, maybe? The final table should look like that:

```
   id param1 param2  X  Y  Z
0   1    foo     fo  1  1  1
1   2    bar     ba  1  0  1
2   3     fu    bar  0  1  0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) with [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), then values are converted to `bool` - `0` to `False` and `1,2...` to `True`. Last values are converted to `int` - `0` and `1`:

```
print (df1.join(df2.groupby(['id', 'item'])
                   .size()
                   .unstack(fill_value=0)
                   .astype(bool)
                   .astype(int), on='id'))

   id param1 param2  X  Y  Z
0   1    foo     fo  1  1  1
1   2    bar     ba  1  0  1
2   3     fu    bar  0  1  0
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (df1.join(pd.crosstab(df2['id'], df2['item']).astype(bool).astype(int), on='id'))
   id param1 param2  X  Y  Z
0   1    foo     fo  1  1  1
1   2    bar     ba  1  0  1
2   3     fu    bar  0  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just concat them :

```
df_final = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
df_final = df_final.transpose().reset_index().drop_duplicates()
df_final = df_final.set_index('index').transpose()
```

output :

```
    id  param1  param2  X   Y   Z
0   1   foo     fo      1   1   1
1   2   bar     ba      1   0   1
2   3   fu      bar     0   1   0
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question, check out the answer from @jezrael

Comment: @valenzio i changed it to drop the duplicates columns, but i have no ideas why the Z columns disapears

Comment: So if I do it, i get a complete different dataframe. Also the first dataframe is called df1, not df just so it is easier to copy paste

Comment: @valenzio sorry, just figured out what was wrong, drop_duplicates() doesn't take index into account, must be working now.